# A question about expressing 3D rotation matrices

Tags: rotations

In general, how an element $g \in SO(3)$ is characterized?

I know that we are talking about $3D$ rotation matrices, hence I guess that $g=\textbf{R}_g \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$.

But explicitly, is $g \in SO(3)$ generally parametrized by three angles $\alpha,\beta, \gamma$?

Then, how should we express a transformation of this kind?

Comment: I used DuckDuckGo and searched "rotation matrix 3D" and got many results. The first result was an eighteen page paper. Maybe you used Google and they didn't have that?

Comment: I know I have searched a lot of course, but I find many confusional resources which rarely provide me a concrete understanding. So I prefer to ask my perplexities here sometimes hoping that somebody might provide a specific and explanatory answer

Comment: @James There are several different common parameterizations of $SO(3)$, some of which are [listed here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charts_on_SO(3)#Parametrizations). There's also a [list of conversion formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions#Conversion_formulae_between_formalisms) between these

Comment: If you want to characterize $g$ with $3$ angles, then you have choice between the [Euler angles and Tait-Bryan angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles).